# Does traffic coming in from one router go out through the same router?

Tags: networking, router

I'm in the process of switching ISPs so I (temporarily) have both connected. The old ISP provided me with a "sticky" IPv4 address and no IPv6, whereas the new one gives me IPv6 and CGNAT for IPv4. Until I get round to getting an alternative set up, I'm looking to still run some services at home.

Current (new) configuration:

```
Old ISP Router: 192.168.0.1
New ISP Router: 192.168.0.2
Server:         192.168.0.30
```

Currently I have my default gateway set to 192.168.0.1, effectively meaning that all IPv4 traffic goes through the old ISP, and all IPv6 (due to Router Advertisements) goes through the new ISP. The old router is set up to port forward relevant ports to the server. They are primarily TCP connections.

I would like to change my default gateway to 192.168.0.2. If I do this, will the traffic coming in through the old ISP and being port forwarded to the server go back out the same way it came in?

Comment: The packet will go back through the new router, with a source IP address that is different from the destination on the incoming packet. The remote client probably won't recognize it as belonging to the same flow, so it will simply discard it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to change my default gateway to 192.168.0.2. If I do this, will the traffic coming in through the old ISP and being port forwarded to the server go back out the same way it came in?

No, not automatically.

The server will follow its routing table for the reply packets – if its default gateway points to 192.168.0.2, then all outbound packets *including replies* will go through 192.168.0.2 regardless of where inbound packets came from.

(Some operating systems do remember the ingress *interface* when you have two separate networks, each on its own interface – but practically never for multiple gateways on the *same* interface.)

Linux-based servers can use "policy routing" to decide between several default routes; you can combine this with iptables "connection marks" so that any packets that arrive from the MAC address of Router1 get a certain mark, then any outbound packets belonging to the same connection retain that mark, and finally a policy-routing rule directs them through a "default via Router1" route. This will work with anything that conntrack understands, including UDP flows.

(On some BSDs, the same might be achievable with pf, but I think that only supports per-interface stickiness if I remember correctly.)

You *could* also achieve this by having the old router additionally SNAT all packets so that they appear as if coming *from* 192.168.0.1 itself (similar to the setup done for 'NAT hairpin'), but this has the obvious downside that the server will no longer know where the packets are actually coming from – 192.168.0.1 is all your log files will show.

Comment: Reading your answer my solution is obvious... I can manually set the default gateway on the server to be the old ISP, whereas the default gateway for the _rest_ of the network can be the new ISP